# Combine colors in one theme

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles, material-components, material-components-android

I'd like to create themes parent `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar` and `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight`. But I don't want to duplicate the colors in them, like

```
<resources>

<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/color_primary_variant</item>
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/color_secondary</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/color_secondary_variant</item>

    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/color_background</item>
    <item name="colorSurface">@color/color_surface</item>
    <item name="colorError">@color/color_error</item>

    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/color_on_primary</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/color_on_secondary</item>
    <item name="colorOnBackground">@color/color_on_background</item>
    <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/color_on_surface</item>
    <item name="colorOnError">@color/color_on_error</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Base.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/color_primary_variant</item>
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/color_secondary</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/color_secondary_variant</item>

    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/color_background</item>
    <item name="colorSurface">@color/color_surface</item>
    <item name="colorError">@color/color_error</item>

    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/color_on_primary</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/color_on_secondary</item>
    <item name="colorOnBackground">@color/color_on_background</item>
    <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/color_on_surface</item>
    <item name="colorOnError">@color/color_on_error</item>
</style>
```

Can I combine colors into one theme and inherit in 2 themes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
   <!-- add the colors -->
</style>


<style name="AppTheme.Base.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

In this way the `AppTheme.Base.NoActionBar` style **inherits all styles** from the `AppTheme.Base` style above and adds the `windowActionBar` `windowNoTitle` attribute.

Also check the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes#Customize):

> Note: If you use the dot notation to extend a style, and you also include the parent attribute, then the parent styles **override** any styles inheritted through the dot notation.